# Why isn't android app restriction available for google directions api?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So apparently android app restriction doesn't work when I call google directions API from my android app I still get the Your IP is restricted etc.

So I apparently googled and read somewhere that Android app restriction is valid only for Google Maps Android API v2 and Google Maps Places for Android.

The question is why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directions API is a web service and it is supposed to be called from your backend server, not from mobile device directly. The API keys for web services support only IP address restriction. So, in order to protect an API key that you are going to use with web service requests you should create an intermediate server that will send requests to Google and pass responses back to your Android app. To protect an API key you should use an IP address of your intermediate server.

There is a feature request in the Google issue tracker to add services similar to Maps JavaScript API v3 directly in Maps Android API v2:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822353

Feel free to star the feature request to express your interest and subscribe to further notifications.

Hope this addresses your doubt.

Comment: Can you answer this question too for me? Thanks :) 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45642278/questions-on-avoid-tollroads-in-google-directions-api

Answer (score 0):

I think there are  also restrictions in google direction API. You can pass your API key in the URL(parameter is *key*). For example

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=75+9th+Ave+New+York,+NY&destination=MetLife+Stadium+1+MetLife+Stadium+Dr+East+Rutherford,+NJ+07073&key=YOUR_API_KEY

For more details:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: You're missing my point. Let's say you have google API string let's call it A. You are restricting A to be able to used only in your android app. If you are displaying Google Maps in your app using A, everything is fine. But then you call call the google directions API using A and it won't work, although you are making the call from the android app, this shouldn't be a problem. However, according to a google search I made, it says that Android app restriction is valid only for Google Maps Android API v2 and Google Maps Places for Android so my question is simply, why?

Comment: Did u enable direction api in developer console for your key? It should work like that..

Comment: I can confirm that Directions API are not working with restriction to Android app. You have to restrict to IP or make it unrestricted, which is silly...in that case, you need to ask your server to give you routes, or create some intermediate server in Android which is also silly...