# Questions on avoid=tollroads in Google Directions API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a few questions on the Google Directions API.

1. Does avoid=tollroads in Google Directions API completely avoids partial toll roads? Or is it smart enough to know that there are routes that can go on partial toll roads but doesn't actually get to the parts on the partial toll roads that require toll road payments (for example if it notices the route exits the partial toll road before it gets to the part where you need to pay)?
2. If in order to get from A to B, you have to cross a toll road in order to get to the destination, when using avoid=tollroads, will it still return routes with that necessary toll road in it or will it return no results?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

1. No. Tolls are avoided when reasonable, not as a top priority. Taking a detour that takes much longer (time) just to avoid tolls is not necessarily (or even likely) going to be among the routes included when using `avoid=tolls`. This also applies to routes with partial tolls.
2. Yes. Just as tolls are not avoided in the situation above, they'll certainly won't present an obstable to reach a destination.